# In T3: Why is there an apparent discrepancy in the Terminator's knowledge of human emotions?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-3-rise-of-the-machines

In the first scene, the terminator claims to have knowledge of basic human psychology

> Terminator:  Anger is more useful than despair.
>
> John: What?
>
> Terminator: Basic psychology is among my sub-routines.

However, in a subsequent scene just a little later, the Terminator claims ignorance of a basic human psychological situation, interpersonal relationships (a.k.a. human pair bonding)

> [John asks the Terminator about the revelation that Kate is actually his future wife]
>
> John: Are you sure about this... me and her?
>
> Terminator: Your confusion is not rational. She is a healthy female of breeding age.
>
> John: Well, I think there's a little more to it than that...
>
> Terminator: My database does not encompass the dynamics of human pair bonding.

This doesn't seem to match up.

The Wiki Psychology site specifically defines psychology as exploring such relationships:

Wiki quote: "Psychologists explore concepts such as perception, cognition, attention, emotion, phenomenology, motivation, brain functioning, personality, behavior, and **interpersonal relationships**."  (emphasis mine)

Knowledge of how such relationships would be a valuable tool in dealing militarily with humans in such areas as hostages, terror attacks against families, the ability to draw out family members to kill them, etc.  You would think a Terminator psychology routine would include such information.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychology

Comment: Most people don't consider relationships to be simple enough for "basic psychology"...

Comment: I don't know, I think if you concatenate the two lines it seems totally reasonable: "Basic psychology is among my subroutines, but my database does not encompass the dynamics of human pair bonding." Fair enough, invincible robot assassin. Fair enough.

Answer (score 10):

1. As anyone who's ever been in a human pair bonding (or tried dating) can tell you, there's nothing "basic" about the dynamics.
2. Yes, they're both explored in Psychology... just like "the movement of a stone dropped from a table" and an "interaction between a bunch of quarks" are both explored in Physics. There's a marked difference in the difficulty of exploration.
3. Terminators do NOT need to pretend to be in a relationship, and only need to know the "statics" of human pair bonding for the tasks you outlined (hostages, terror attacks against families, the ability to draw out family members to kill them). You don't need to understand **WHY** humans are or aren't attracted, just when two humans **ARE**.

Comment: Thank you for taking time review and answer.  I would absolutely agree that there is nothing basic about human pair bonding dynamics.  However, I am not questioning that the Terminator doesn't understand all the dynamics (I've been married 24 years and don't pretend to understand. :-)  )  But, a basic psychology routine should at least recognize that there ARE more complex human dynamics involved than simple sexual interaction.   The Terminator seemed unfamiliar that there even was anything beyond simply sex that would/could supersede a sexual relationship.  That seems like a gap.

Comment: @beichst - perhaps Terminator is into PAU scene?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with DVK

however to expand

the terminator is a learning computer and it is trying to learn the dynamics of human pair bonding

the terminator is starting at the most basic level of inquiry (I know nothing)

Answer (score 0):

To reference the [OP's comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39547/in-t3-why-is-there-an-apparent-discrepancy-in-the-terminators-knowledge-of-hum#comment75317_39552) on DVK's answer, the Terminator isn't referring to sex, but more specifically to procreation ("`healthy female of breeding age`"). Apparently the only purpose it sees in pair-bonding is for procreation and the continuance of the species.

From a computer's point of view (the Terminator's, Skynet's) this makes sense. Animals pair off to breed and continue the species into the next generation. Even monogamous animal bonding isn't extraordinary to humans, as it is observed among lower animal forms.

Thus, it isn't too strange that a Terminator may have basic psychological programming specific to manipulating individual humans or small groups of humans for a tactical advantage (as DVK answered). But the programming to explain the courtship between paired humans, specific to why or how they decided to pair up, would be less important. After all, Skynet isn't trying to play matchmaker or marriage counselor for the remaining beleaguered humans.